# Migración de GAM 4.0.4 a 4.0.5

Tags: .net, genexus

Estoy con GX17u5 plataforma .NET

estuve siguiendo los pasos que indica este doc
[How to migrate from GAM version 4.0.4 to 4.0.5](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48526,How%20to%20migrate%20from%20GAM%20version%204.0.4%20to%204.0.5) 
para tener mi sistema actualizado a la última versión GAM.

Primero ejecuté la reorg que se indica exitosamente: ReorganizationScript404To405.txt

Luego ejecuté la migración de datos:
[image: Migracion datos]

Copié el archivo **connection.gam** generado en /bin a /web como indica el doc. Sucede que me da el error:

> **La conexión al GAM no fue encontrada, por favor contacte al administrador del GAM.**

[image: Error al login]

En contenido del archivo connection.gam es:

[image: Connection.gam]

¿Hay alguna forma de verificar el proceso de migración y ver que falló? ¿Se puede regenerar el archivo connection.gam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La key que está en el archivo connection.gam es el identificador de los datos de conexión almacenados en la tabla [SysConnectionConfig]. Puedes verificar que en esa tabla exista al menos un registro y si esa key del archivo coincide con el valor del campo [SysConnCfgKey] para al menos un registro.

El mensaje de error está indicando que no encuentra los datos de conexión basado en la key que está en el archivo connection.gam.

Comment: Excelente! No existía ese valor para ninguno de los que había en la tabla. Lo cambié por el 1ro y anduvo impecable! Gracias Eugenio!